# Decision Tree Classifier to classify values based on values of other columns

Tags: python, classification, decision-trees, multilabel-classification

I have data with multiple labels, for example

[image]

My **X** set is fromt **second** to **third** column, and I want to classify either **first** column or the **last** column, so I made my **Y** the last column.

The goal is so that if I would classify Vios it would return me **Car** or **0** in other words it can find its way to the **first row**.

Classification use case:

```
classify("poodle") #just pretend this is a working function
```

returns: Pets

How I did it in attempt to train my model:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 72)
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
clf3 = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
```

I'm using a guide from somewhere on the net that works a bit the same with it, but at the end im getting returned:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5, 4156]
```

I knew immediately i was doing it wrong. How do I train a model so that it achieves my goal? Any relevant guides or techniques I should be following intead of [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-12f1e60e0a9f)? I dont even know the correct way to use vectors on this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Couple of things:**
Cant replicate the problem exactly but if you follow these steps you are not exposing yourself

**TfidfVectorizer is CountVectorizer + TfidfTransformer**, you are exposing yourself to unnecessary complexity and potential errors

Use [pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), cant stress this enough, its a compact way to pack all the sklearn transformers together **AND THEN** use fit, predict methods...

I would advise you to follow something like that, or find similiar problem [here](https://www.kaggle.com/)

Comment: thabks, but do you think my method of vectorizing it in order to classify it would work in this kind of problem in the first place?

Comment: I would try Countvectorizer and Tf-idf sperately and they should give good results

Comment: Im a bit confused when only using vectorizer, heres my data: https://prnt.sc/qdm2iz

Vectorized it: https://prnt.sc/qdm2rs,  when correlating im getting this error: https://prnt.sc/qdm2y7

as such I cant fit it to any of my models: https://prnt.sc/qdm38s

Comment: I have already categorized it by id: https://prnt.sc/qdm3v6, so whats left is to train a model with the 'combined' column, that is vectorized, then  i thought id be able to predict to which category it belongs to.

Comment: This is why I thought having a countvectorizer would do the trick, I think this is a factor of how I arrange my data? Im using bagging method to classify, if a vector belong from 1 to 19 categories

Comment: There is like 3 questions you are asking right now. Do you know why you are using chi2 for features selection (where is your categorical data, and why do you need it?) etc etc. I would ask you kindly to reformulate your series of questions a little bit and then ask them seperately or find answers on stack. Regarding your first question on this post. I still dont know if you can perform clf3 = RandomForestClassifier().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train) If you followed what I told, it should not be a problem. In that case, if you are satisfied accept this question, and ask others which I will answer.